# BoxWhiskerChart: How to combine more than one extra ingredients?

Tags: charts

For instance, `"Diamond"` and `"Outliers"` in single plot.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 0.5], 100], "Outliers",  "Diamond"]
```

generates an error, as well as

```
BoxWhiskerChart[RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 0.5], 100], {"Outliers",  "Diamond"}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data= RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[1, 0.5], 100] ;
BoxWhiskerChart[data, {"Diamond",{ "Outliers"} }, ImageSize->300]
```

[image]

`"Diamond"` and `"MeanDiamond"` both represent "mean confidence interval", but the latter can be used with parameters *width* and *style*.

```
Row[{BoxWhiskerChart[data, {{"MeanDiamond"}, {"Outliers"}}, ImageSize->300],
  BoxWhiskerChart[data, {"Diamond", {"Outliers"} }, ImageSize -> 300] }]
```

[image]

Same is true for `"Notched"` and `"MedianNotch"`.

The documentation is not clear about how different elements can be combined. From checking various combinations it seems that at most one of the

```
"Basic" 
"Outliers"
"Notched"
"Median"
"Mean"
"Diamond"
```

can appear in a specification. Each of these elements can be combined with any number of the following:

```
 {"Fences", width, style}
 {"MeanDiamond",width,style}
 {"MeanMarker",width,style}
 {"MedianNotch",width,style}
 {"MedianMarker",width,style}
 {"Outliers",marker,style}
 {"FarOutliers",marker,style}
 {"Whiskers",style}
```